# MVVM usage with kendo ui framework

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, kendo-ui, signalr

I have two views having their own view models. One of them contains just a grid and the other contains a form. I'm loading two of them dynamically at the same time.

Here is the view model of my view conatining grid:

```
$(function () {

var ticker = $.connection.marketWatch;
var initializationData = null; // marketWatchData 
function init() {
    return ticker.server.getAllMarketWatchData().done(function (data) {

        initializationData = data;

        $("#marketWatchGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(data);
    });
}

// Add client-side hub methods that the server will call
$.extend(ticker.client, {
    updateMarketWatchData: function (marketWatchData) {
        // do something...
    }
});

// Start the connection
$.connection.hub.start()
    .pipe(init)
    .done(function () {
        viewModelMarketRates.data = initializationData;

        viewModelOrder.updateInstruments();
    });
});

var viewModelMarketRates = kendo.observable({
    data: null
});

kendo.bind($("#marketWatchGrid"), viewModelMarketRates);
```

And the view model of my view containing form:

```
$(function () {
var viewModelOrder = kendo.observable({
    instruments: viewModelMarketRates.data,
    selectedInstrument: "EURUSD",
    amount: "0.1",
    slActivate: false,
    sl: "0.0",
    tpActivate: false,
    tp: "0.0",
    buy: function () {
        //e.preventDefault();

        //alert("buy");
    },
    sell: function () {
        //e.preventDefault();

        //alert("sell");
    },
    updateInstruments: function () {
        this.set("instruments", viewModelMarketRates.data);
        this.set("selectedInstrument", "EURUSD");
    }
});

//viewModelOrder.instruments = viewModelMarketRates.data;
//alert(viewModelOrder.instruments.length);
kendo.bind($("#orderForm"), viewModelOrder);
});
```

As you see I'm getting market rates data in init function and storing it in data attribute of viewModelMarketRates. I call updateInstruments function of viewModelOrder but in firebug I'm getting the following error:

**ReferenceError: viewModelOrder is not defined**

**viewModelOrder.updateInstruments();**

How can I prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The source of your problem is that your viewModelOrder is in different scope than grid's document ready.
2. You shouldn't reference function/objects from multiple dynamically loaded views that load at the same time. What if one loads later than the other? Or don't load at all?

Easiest solution I can think of atm:
1. Sync the views. Load form after grid.
2. Move content of grid's document ready to a

```
function grid_ready(){
//all that ticker and connections start stuff
}
```

and use that function in form's document ready

```
$(function(){
//create view model etc,
grid_ready();
});
```

edit: grammar.